# laravel implementing two script in one page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

As I'm using script for autocomplete inputs, the problem is one of them work and the other doesn't work so how can I solve this issue?

```
<input class="ventypeahead form-control"  type="text" placeholder="category">

<script type="text/javascript">
  var path = "{{ route('autocompletecategory') }}";
  $('input.cattypeahead').typeahead({
    source:  function (query, process) {
      return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
        return process(data);
      });
    }
  });
</script>

<input class="cattypeahead form-control"  type="text" >

<script type="text/javascript">
  var path = "{{ route('autocompletevendor') }}";
  $('input.ventypeahead').typeahead({
    source:  function (query, process) {
      return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
        return process(data);
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Which one does not work?

Comment: how about trying to switch the script places? I would guess that one probable cause could be that your first script tries to add the autocomplete to input element which doesn't exist yet at that point ("cattypeahead" input is created after the script where you try to attach the autocomplete to it). Or better yet, why not use document ready function to add those autocompletes to be sure that the dom elements exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is using `var path` two times and `wrong class in wrong place` or `using input in wrong place`,

**Just reverse the class name and also change variable names,**

```
 <input class="ventypeahead form-control"  type="text" placeholder="category">

  <script type="text/javascript">
  var path1 = "{{ route('autocompletecategory') }}";
   $('input.ventypeahead').typeahead({
    source:  function (query, process) {
    return $.get(path1, { query: query }, function (data) {
            return process(data);
        });
      }
     });
 </script>

 <input class="cattypeahead form-control"  type="text" >

 <script type="text/javascript">
  var path2 = "{{ route('autocompletevendor') }}";
  $('input.cattypeahead').typeahead({
    source:  function (query, process) {
    return $.get(path2, { query: query }, function (data) {
            return process(data);
        });
       }
     });
  </script>
```